# Appstore upload rejected after adding Firebase In-AppMessaging and CloudMessaging

Tags: ios, firebase, app-store, appstore-approval

I got the following mail from AppStore when I uploaded my app recently,

> App Store Connect   Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,
>   . Please correct the following issues, then upload again.
>
> "Missing Purpose String in Info.plist File. Your app's code references
>   one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist
>   file should contain a NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key with a
>   user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your
>   app needs the data. Starting spring 2019, all apps submitted to the
>   App Store that access user data will be required to include a purpose
>   string.If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference
>   APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these
>   APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the
>   developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of
>   their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more
>   (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy)."
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

I understand we need to add Location permission text in the info.plist as per the above mail,
And I tried to add the same but still my upload got rejected stating the same mail.

Please let me know how to handle this based on following case,

- My app doesn't need/have location permission yet.

Comment: Please check this solution for Apple's guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/a/55411592/5084797

Comment: in your app have u used  anywhere location based concept

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik No, I haven't used any location based concept, If I had used just mentioning the detail as I did on first iteration would have fixed my issue. But I haven't asked user for permission explicitly.

Comment: Maybe some SDK that you are using would be trying to access Location. It would be better if you can add it and upload the build.